# Collectcd-core package not installing

Tags: apt, package-management

In an effort to find a faster repository server, I inadvertently copied an apt-spy command that pointed me at a "testing" version of Debian. I then attempted to return the system to a stable version (Wheezy) by re running apt-spy with the appropriate package switch.  I am now running into issues when I run apt-get update with the following error message:

```
Starting statistics collection and monitoring daemon: collectdERROR: lt_dlopen ("/usr/lib/collectd/rrdcached.so") failed: file not found. The most common cause for this problem is missing dependencies. Use ldd(1) to check the dependencies of the plugin / shared object.
Error: Reading the config file failed!
Read the syslog for details.
 not starting, configuration error failed!
invoke-rc.d: initscript collectd, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package collectd-core (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 collectd-core
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

If I try to update using:

```
dpkg-reconfigure -phigh collectd-core
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Reading the config file failed!
Read the syslog for details.
 not starting, configuration error failed!
invoke-rc.d: initscript collectd, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package collectd-core (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of collectd:
 collectd depends on collectd-core; however:
  Package collectd-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package collectd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 collectd-core
 collectd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am relatively new to Linux and have been trolling through Google to try and find a solution to no avail.  Any suggestions?

A little mode info, if I run "ldd /usr/lib/collectd/rrdcached.so ", I receive the following (trying to install anything now with apt-get returns an error related to this file):

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc931e8000)
librrd.so.8 => not found
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa7c88d8000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa7c8e80000)
```

Comment: Update: If I try to configure the collectd-core package with:

Comment: anything with apt-get install -f ?

Comment: No dice:  'Error: Reading the config file failed!
Read the syslog for details.
 not starting, configuration error failed!
invoke-rc.d: initscript collectd, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package collectd-core (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of collectd:
 collectd depends on collectd-core; however:
  Package collectd-core is not configured yet.

Comment: 'dpkg: error processing package collectd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 collectd-core
 collectd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)'

Answer (score 2):

OK, looks like the following has worked (which makes sense):

```
apt-get remove --auto-remove collectd-core
apt-get purge --auto-remove collectd-core
apt-get update
apt-get --yes install collectd
```

I can now install packages with apt-get again.